# oracle pass list of string as parameter

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to pass list of string as parameter

when my query is generated from my application I have this sql code :

```
SELECT * FROM Transfers TRANSFERS 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN correspondence_copy CORRESPCPY on CORRESPCPY.ID_COPY = TRANSFERS.ID_COPY  
  WHERE TRANSFERS.ORDERNBR in ('[236359981, 236359982, 236359983]')
```

this is the source code in jave where I used List

```
 public List<SupEntity> sendSup(List<String> listOrderNumber)
        throws Exception {


         String query_tr = " SELECT * ";


        query_tr += " FROM Transfers TRANSFERS ";
        query_tr +=" LEFT OUTER JOIN correspondence_copy CORRESPCPY on CORRESPCPY.ID_COPY = TRANSFERS.ID_COPY  " ;

        query_tr +=" WHERE TRANSFERS.ORDERNBR in ('" +listOrderNumber + "')";


            SQLQuery sqlQuery = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(query_tr);


            sqlQuery.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(
                    SupEntity.class));

            List list = sqlQuery.list();

            return list;
        }
```

I call this methode from this code :

```
   public SupListEntity getsupList(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        SupListEntity supListEntity)
        throws Exception {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
         List<CorrespondenceEntity> sendsupList =new ArrayList<SupEntity>();
        String [] tabOrder=null;

                if(supListEntity.getId()!=null)
                {

                    tabOrder=supListEntity.getId().split(",");
                    if(tabOrder!=null && tabOrder.length>0)
                    {
                        for(int i=0;i<tabOrder.length;i++)
                        {
                            list.add(tabOrder[i]);

                        }
                        sendsupList = supDAO.sendSup(list);
                          supListEntity.setCorrespondenceList(sendsupList); 

                    }



                }

        return supListEntity;
    }
```

so the problem that my query which is generaed has this kind of code :

**in ('[236359981, 236359982, 236359983]')**    which is false 
 it should be like this 
**in ('236359981', '236359982', '236359983')**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
String query_tr = " SELECT * ";
       query_tr += " FROM Transfers TRANSFERS ";
       query_tr +=" LEFT OUTER JOIN correspondence_copy CORRESPCPY on CORRESPCPY.ID_COPY = TRANSFERS.ID_COPY  " ;
       query_tr +=" WHERE TRANSFERS.ORDERNBR in (:list)";

SQLQuery sqlQuery = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(query_tr);
sqlQuery.setParameterList("list", listOrderNumber)
```